# Apex Trigger Error

Tags: apex, class, after-trigger

Here is my Apex Class:

```
public class NavProductHelperClass {
    public void checkProductAvailability(list<OpportunityLineItem> opids) {
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli: opids) { 
            Opportunity opps;
            id OppLineItemID = oli.ID ;
            system.debug(
                'Opportunity line item triggered ' + oli.Opp_Line_Item_Id__c  + 
                'Opportunity ID ' + oli.ID + ' Product code' + oli.ProductCode
            );

            opps =  [
                Select oli.First_Ship_Date__c, oli.Expected_Return_Ship_Date__c, 
                    oli.Min_K_QPID__c, oli.Min_K_DS_WIFI_1__c, (
                        Select Quantity, productcode
                        From OpportunityLineItems
                        WHERE ProductCode =:oli.ProductCode 
                    )
                From Opportunity oli 
                Where id IN (
                    SELECT OpportunityId 
                    FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                    WHERE Quantity > 0 and id =:oli.id
                )
            ];

            OpportunityLineItem prod;

            prod = [
                Select Quantity, productcode, Nav_Inventory__c  
                From OpportunityLineItem 
                where Opp_Line_Item_Id__c =:oli.Opp_Line_Item_Id__c
            ];

            if(oli.ProductCode == 'K-QPID') {
                Datascan_Product_Availability__c Avail = [
                    select K_QPID__c , Count_Date__c 
                    From Datascan_Product_Availability__c c 
                    where (c.Count_Date__c > :opps.First_Ship_Date__c) 
                        and (c.Count_Date__c < :opps.Expected_Return_Ship_Date__c) 
                    order by K_QPID__c asc limit 1
                ];

                opps.Min_K_QPID__c  = Avail.K_QPID__c ;
                opps.Min_K_QPID_Date__c = Avail.Count_Date__c;
            } else {
                Datascan_Product_Availability__c Avail2 = [
                    select K_DS_WIFI_1__c, Count_Date__c 
                    From Datascan_Product_Availability__c d
                    where (d.Count_Date__c > :opps.First_Ship_Date__c) 
                        and (d.Count_Date__c <  :opps.Expected_Return_Ship_Date__c) 
                    order by K_DS_WIFI_1__c asc limit 1 
                ];

                opps.Min_K_DS_WIFI_1__c = Avail2.K_DS_WIFI_1__c ;
                opps.Min_K_DS_WIFI_1_Date__c = Avail2.Count_Date__c ;
            }

            update opps;           

            system.debug('opps ' + opps.First_Ship_Date__c + opps.Expected_Return_Ship_Date__c );
            system.debug('prod ' + prod.quantity + prod.productcode );
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as intended. But it errors out on all Opportunities which does not have these products added. I technically have to find if the product quantities are available only for these two products and not check for any other.

Here is error I get :

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Review all error messages below to correct your data.
>   Apex trigger NavProductTriigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: NavProductTriigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0060W00000zqcx7QAA; first error: FIELD_FILTER_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Value does not exist or does not match filter criteria.: [Program_Load__c]: Class.NavProductHelperClass.checkProductAvailability: line 40, column 1

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Can you [edit] this post to help us connect the dots? This error looks like it's coming from a Lookup Field Filter whose lookup (`Program_Load__c`) you do not populate here. What is the filter's content? How is the field populated?

Comment: This code is also in desperate need of bulkification and will throw limit errors pretty fast as volume scales.

Comment: Got it, I have fixed the lookup error. Can you please help me understand your second part on bulkification?

Comment: I recommend completing this [Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk). You are running many SOQL queries in loops.

Comment: @sylseb According to your comment you were able to solve your own issue. Please write an answer to this question with what you did to resolve your own issue. There will be a waiting period before you can accept your own answer so please make sure to come back and accept it.

Comment: Added an exception handling so this scenario where the Program_Load__c is not available.